# Why can't I change variables in a protocol extension where self is a class?

Tags: swift, protocols

I am curious why this doesn't work:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    var i: Int { get set }
}

public protocol MyProtocol2: class, MyProtocol {}

public extension MyProtocol2 where Self: AnyObject {
    func a() {
        i = 0 <-- error
    }
}
```

Error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable

Why? Only classes can adopt MyProtocol2. If I add `: class` declaration behind MyProtocol it works. I do not understand why it doesn't work on a subprotocol.

Comment: If `MyProtocol` isn't constrained to class types, then the function `a` would be allowed to mutate it, without explicitly being marked `mutating`.

Comment: use it like->  mutating func a()

Comment: @Alexander How do you mean? Only things that conform to MyProtocol2 can call func a(). That 'things' can only be classes. I do not get it why it needs to be mutating.

Comment: If I constrain `MyProtocol` to class instead of `MyProtocol2`then the error goes away which makes sense to me since `i` is a property of the first protocol so I also fail to understand your comment @Alexander

Comment: @J.Doe Instances of `MyProtocol2` are instances of `MyProtocol`. Mutations of `i` are actually mutations of `self.i`, which are mutations of `self`. Such mutations, on value types (structs, enums) can only be made by `mutating func`s. Class functions don't need such a `mutating` qualifier to mutate self. That's why making `MyProtocol` class-bound resolves the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example doesn't compile because `MyProtocol` isn't class-bound, and as such can have `mutating` requirements and extension members. This includes property setters, which are by default `mutating`. Such members are free to re-assign a *completely new* value to `self`, meaning that the compiler needs to ensure they're called on mutable variables.

For example, consider:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  init()
  var i: Int { get set } // implicitly `{ get mutating set }`
}

extension MyProtocol {
  var i: Int {
    get { return 0 }
    // implicitly `mutating set`
    set { self = type(of: self).init() } // assign a completely new instance to `self`.
  }
}

public protocol MyProtocol2 : class, MyProtocol {}

public extension MyProtocol2 where Self : AnyObject {
  func a() {
    i = 0 // error: Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable
  }
}

final class C : MyProtocol2 {
  init() {}
}

let c = C()
c.a()
```

If this were legal, calling `c.a()` would re-assign a completely new instance of `C` to the variable `c`. But `c` is immutable, therefore the code is not well formed.

Making `MyProtocol` class bound (i.e `protocol MyProtocol : AnyObject` or the deprecated spelling `protocol MyProtocol : class`) works because now the compiler knows that only classes can conform to `MyProtocol`. Therefore it imposes reference semantics by forbidding `mutating` requirements and extension members and therefore prevents any mutations of `self`.

Another option at your disposal is to mark the setter for the requirement `i` as being `nonmutating` – therefore meaning that it can only be satisfied by a non-mutating setter. This makes your code once again well-formed:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  init()
  var i: Int { get nonmutating set }
}

public protocol MyProtocol2 : class, MyProtocol {}

public extension MyProtocol2 where Self : AnyObject {
  func a() {
    i = 0 // legal
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Those examples are really helpful :). I forgot about the property setter.

Comment: Hi Hamish, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729852/how-can-i-correctly-use-associatedtype-in-my-protocol Can you take a look into that?

Answer (score 0):

Property setters trigger mutation on the callee, which means that any method that  operates on the property needs to be declared as `mutating`:

```
public extension MyProtocol2 where Self: AnyObject {
    mutating func a() {
        i = 0
    }
}
```

This will allow any writes on `self` within the method.