# Instance is necessarily treated as value type in extensions of non-class-bound protocols

Tags: swift, protocols, immutability, value-type, protocol-extension

Here's the code:

```
protocol A {
  var a: Int { get set }
}

extension A {
  var convenientAccessor: Int {
    get { return a }
    set { a = newValue }
  }
}

class B: A {
  var a: Int = 0
}

func acceptsB (instance: B) {
  instance.a = 1                     // This compiles
  instance.convenientAccessor = 2    // This does not
}
```

I sort of understand the problem here, but I really would love both an answer from someone who understands it more deeply, and more importantly a workaround for my problem which is that I want to pass around known class types and be able to use convenient accessors without being inhibited by the non-possibility that I'm using a value type. In my case, the protocols which define these convenient accessors should not be class-bound (they are perfectly valid and useful for value types), so while that is technically a workaround, it is not satisfactory to me.

Comment: A (perhaps not satisfying) workaround would be to add `var instance = instance` at the start of the function.

Comment: This is a tricky case because unlike class members, `mutating` protocol extension members (which by default includes the setter for `convenientAccessor`) are able to assign a completely new value to `self` – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/51678708/2976878.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a summary: `convenientAccessor` is a writable property, thus any assignment on it will result in a mutation. And this mutation happens inside your function.

The thing is that when the `convenientAccessor` property is used the compiler treats `instance` as protocol `A`, and because arguments to a function are `let`'s, it doesn't allow mutations on them, as at this point the protocol can be implemented by a value type also.

Two solutions that come into my mind are:

1. restrict protocol `A` to only classes:

   ```
   protocol A: class
   ```

   This informs the compiler that only classes can conform to the protocol, which allows the mutation on any kind of variables (`let` or `var`)
2. make the function parameter `inout`:

   ```
   func acceptsB (instance: inout B)
   ```

   This creates a "write hole" as now `instance` is writable, so any changes to it are propagated back upstream, even if `B` is a value type.

Personally, I'd go with #1 if you plan in using only classes, as you mentioned in the question.