# How can I correctly use associatedType in my protocol

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swift-protocols, associated-types

I’m trying to come up with an protocol-oriented MVVM for my tableviewcells. I have lots of them.

my `viewModel`

```
protocol PlainTableViewCellModelType {
    var backgroundColor : UIColor {get}
    var textColor: UIColor {get}
    var titleFont : UIFont {get }
    var accessoryType : UITableViewCellAccessoryType {get}
    var textLabelNumberOfLines: Int {get}
}
```

my `view`

```
protocol PlainTableViewCellType{
    associatedtype viewModel : PlainTableViewCellModelType
    func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: viewModel)
}
```

my `class` conformance

```
class PlainTableViewCell : CCTableViewCell, PlainTableViewCellType{

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: PlainTableViewCellModelType){
        contentView.backgroundColor = viewModel.backgroundColor
        textLabel?.textColor = viewModel.textColor
        textLabel?.font = viewModel.titleFont
        accessoryType = viewModel.accessoryType
        textLabel?.numberOfLines = viewModel.textLabelNumberOfLines
    }
}
```

The current setups results in the following error:

> Type 'PlainTableViewCell' does not conform to protocol
>   'PlainTableViewCellType'

I can get it to work if I do:

```
protocol PlainTableViewCellType{
    func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: PlainTableViewCellModelType)
}
```

But I want to have an `associatedType` so I can enforce same model in all my `PlainTableViewCellType` functions

**EDIT:**
I'm happy to listen to alternatives, but first I want to know **why** this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think you really need to add a dataType to an associatedType. Correct me if Im wrong, I just thought associatedType are just placeholders for your protocol where in the class that conforms to it is where you set the typeAlias for the associated type. You can get it to work by changing from associatedType to direct protocol instance on setupUI since you are explicitly specifying what class/protocol you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks. Did you read the last line of my question? I want to constrain the associatedType and have uniformity of type across multiple functions of my protocol

Comment: then instead of `associatedtype viewModel : PlainTableViewCellModelType` shouldn't it be  `associatedtype viewModel = PlainTableViewCellModelType` ? directly assigning the value of the associatedType. For the why, I believe that associatedType needs a value and you only did a dataType cast

Comment: This is the classic problem of [protocols not conforming to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) – the `viewModel` associated type cannot be satisfied by `PlainTableViewCellModelType`, as that's not currently a type that conforms to `PlainTableViewCellModelType` (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/37360114/2976878 which is specific to associated types).

Answer (score 1):

In protocol you need remove *PlainTableViewCellModelType*:

```
protocol PlainTableViewCellType{
    associatedtype viewModel
    func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: viewModel)
}
```

and in PlainTableViewCell you need add something like this:

```
typealias viewModel = PlainTableViewCellModelType
```

Comment: _you need remove PlainTableViewCellModelType_ I would like constrain it though.

Comment: then you don't need associatedtype, just write func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: PlainTableViewCellType)

Comment: right. But what if I want I 2 other functions in my protocol **and** want all of them to have the same parameter type

Comment: apart from that I still don't get why removing `PlainTableViewCellModelType` from `viewModel: PlainTableViewCellModelType` resolves the issue. That's the core of my question

Comment: and typealias viewModel = PlainTableViewCellModelType in PlainTableViewCell not help?

Answer (score 1):

You must create `PlainTableViewCellModelType` implementation and declare `typealias` in cell implementation. Use it as type for parameter in `setupUI(forViewModel:)` because compiler cant infer associated type.

```
protocol PlainTableViewCellModelType {
    var backgroundColor : UIColor { get }
    var textColor: UIColor { get }
    var titleFont : UIFont { get }
    var accessoryType : Int { get}
    var textLabelNumberOfLines: Int { get }
}

protocol PlainTableViewCellType{
    associatedtype viewModel : PlainTableViewCellModelType
    func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: viewModel)
}

struct PlainTableViewCellModel: PlainTableViewCellModelType {
    var backgroundColor : UIColor
    var textColor: UIColor
    var titleFont : UIFont
    var accessoryType : Int
    var textLabelNumberOfLines: Int
}


class PlainTableViewCell : UITableViewCell, PlainTableViewCellType {
    typealias viewModel = PlainTableViewCellModel

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    func setupUI(forViewModel viewModel: PlainTableViewCellModel) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = viewModel.backgroundColor
        textLabel?.textColor = viewModel.textColor
        textLabel?.font = viewModel.titleFont
        textLabel?.numberOfLines = viewModel.textLabelNumberOfLines
    }
}
```

Comment: _because compiler cant infer associated type._ It can. See [here](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/generic-protocols-with-associated-type-7e2b6e079ee2). Just not sure why it can't do it here.

Comment: Because associated type wasn't associated with concrete type implicitly (via declaration in property type) or explicitly (via typealias)